# ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible error when trying to type in a textbox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to type in a textbox that is pre-filled with some other text.. Its kind of a text box that also acts like a drop-down (You can type in that box and it brings the matching text like a drop down.).  to type in it. The actions i am performing on the page are, scrolling down the page, trying to locate the element (TextBox) and write on it. I am using the below code

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,400)");

```
    Thread.sleep(4000);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.cssSelector("#reg_country"))); //examining the cssselector for a search       

    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement RegisteredCountry = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#reg_country"));
    RegisteredCountry.sendKeys("Afghanistan");
```

I have also tried Implicit Wait before typing on the element. But its unsucessful. Below is the error i am getting. Please advise

ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible error when trying to type in a textbox

Comment: always remember best way to get help on SO is to show a minimalistic runnable code that shows your issue..with above code it is difficult to judge where your issue might be..and you would receive possible solutions instead.

Comment: I have edited my question.. Please see if you could suggest me anything

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform a click of the text box,then maybe perform a clear before sendkeys.

Comment: No, it didnt work.. I tried clicking on the textbox and then tried typing.. Still i m getting the same error.. Any other suggestion pls?

Answer (score 0):

Few things:
1. Verify that your locator always returns only one object and that is the object which you desire.
2. Run your code in debug mode step by step and see where does it breaks or which control is not visible to selenium. 
3. Inspect that element in Firebug's HTML panel to check if its really visible (or not greyed)
Try to replicate your scenario on one of the public URLs to ensure thats not ur App related issue or selenium related stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`WebElement RegisteredCountry = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#reg_country"));
RegisteredCountry.sendKeys("Afghanistan");
RegisteredCountry.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`

Comment: Sorry,, Didnt work.. Its not typing anything on the textbox.. Any other suggestion perhaps?

Comment: When you use that selector you can get the element while debugging?